# Hide status bar in Android 2 but keep Action Bar in Android 3/4

Tags: android, hide, android-actionbar, statusbar, android-theme

I have been trying out various ways but with no success. I am doing a full screen painting app for kids. But it can't go full screen without the following line in Manifest.xml:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But this statement causes a lot of behaviour issues in Android 3/4 phone/tablets. Either the action bar disappeared, or I got full screen without any access to menu.

Removing the line and with the following code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);        
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Works for Android 3/4 phones, but will have status bar on Android 2!

How can I remove the status bar on Android 2 but still support Android 3/4? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a values-v11 folder.

In your Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</style>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
</style>
```